Database issue in xampp due to reinstall
I use Xampp for Apache and MySQL server to learn Php and work on projects related to Php.
Few Days back when I tried to start the MySQL server it was not able to start so I took a copy of the Data folder and reinstalled the Xampp server.
But not I need one database for the project and its situated in the folder that I copied. But when I put that same folder in the data folder of mysql the tabels are not being loaded and showing error.

Table '[databasename].[tablename]' doesn't exist in engine

Is there any way I can directle import the database fully functional without manually creating the tables from scratch.
I am looking for a method where I can directly use the content from the data folder.
